# Getting the hostname of an SSL client behind a NAT gateway or proxy using java

Tags: java, nat

I have a 2 way SSL client and server written in java. Problem is my server needs to be able to find out the hostname of the client and that client is located behind a NAT gateway or proxy. I have tried:
clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress(),
clientSocket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName(),
clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(),

whereby clientSocket is of type SSLSocket and none of them works, they just give me a public IP address. Is there a way for me to obtain the actual hostname of the client that is connecting to the server?

Comment: There is a roundabout solution, if you have ownership of the application layer protocol. The endpoint address can be sent as an information header as part of the application layer handshake between the server and the client. This obviously depends on you being the developer of the server/client. A good example of this  concept is HTTP, the request header being `X-Forwarded-For` which is user by proxies to send information about the end client (data in the format `X-Forwarded-For: client1, proxy1, proxy2` etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from the Socket. If the remote host is behind a NAT firewall then by definition its hostname and IP address are invisible to you.  All you can see is the public IP and hostname.

However, you could execute a `hostname` command at the remote side and pipe the output back over the SSh connection.  The data you get back will be only as good as the remote host's configuration. There's no guarantee that what you get back matches its internal DNS hostname or anything else.